# Attribute set in a filter can't be retrieved using $request.getAttribute("attributeName")

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, filter

> we implemented some servlets, JSPs and filters and everything was
>   working fine so far. I wan't to track one requestURL for next 2-3
>   requests and I can't save this in session as we are using session for
>   login purpose. But when we tried to set an attribute in the request
>   object and read it from within  a JSP, we always get null values.
>
> In the filter class, we do the following:

```
    String url = ((HttpServletRequest)req).getRequestURL().toString();
    if(url.contains("asc/ascHome")){ 
    HttpServletRequest request         = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    request.setAttribute("OriginURL", "AscHome");
    }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);

> In our login.jsp, we are using the following code to retrieve the
> attribute:

    String originURL = request.getAttribute("OriginURL").toString();

> Is there anything we're missing?
> 
> Filter is as below,

public class SessionAlertFilter  implements Filter {  
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain filterChain) 
            throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) resp;           
    HttpServletRequest httpReq = (HttpServletRequest) req;      
    HttpSession session = httpReq.getSession();
    String str_session_id = session.getId();
    //System.out.println(" session.getMaxInactiveInterval() :"+session.getMaxInactiveInterval());
    long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();            
    //long expiryTime = currTime + (2*60 * 1000);   //25 minutes considering 30 minutes is session timeout
    long expiryTime = currTime + ((session.getMaxInactiveInterval() * 1000) - (5*60*1000));   
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie("serverTime", "" + currTime);            
    cookie.setPath("/");           
    httpResp.addCookie(cookie);  
    //SessionObj session_obj = (SessionObj) session.getAttribute("session_obj");

    if (str_session_id != null) { 
         //System.out.println("session id2------"+str_session_id+" expiryTime: "+expiryTime);
         //showTime(expiryTime);
         cookie = new Cookie("sessionExpiry", "" + expiryTime);           
     } else {                
        cookie = new Cookie("session id2------"+str_session_id+" sessionExpiry", "" + currTime);
        //showTime(expiryTime);
        //System.out.println("currTime: "+currTime);
    }           
    cookie.setPath("/");          
    ((HttpServletResponse) resp).addCookie(cookie); 

    String url = ((HttpServletRequest)req).getRequestURL().toString();
    System.out.println("In Filter.... URL  : "+url);
    if(url.contains("asc/AscHome.jsp")){
        req.setAttribute("OriginURL", "Register_Call");
    }

    filterChain.doFilter(req, resp);
    //checkCookie(httpReq);
}
```

Comment: Try this <%= request.getAttribute("attributeName").toString(); %>

Comment: I am getting values same as above. I just gave sample code. I will update post with my current situation for more understanding

Comment: Are you calling another filter from this filter? Can you write the complete method of filter class?

Comment: Actually I solved the problem with setting counter and int variable in filter.

Comment: Can you write the updated code?

Comment: I am tracking my URL with int Variable and counter instead of setting attribute as below,

Comment: String url = ((HttpServletRequest)req).getRequestURL().toString();
 count++;
 if(count>4){
  count = 0;
  OriginURL = 0;
 }
 System.out.println("In Filter.... URL  : "+url+"count : "+count);
 if(url.contains("asc/AscHome.jsp")){
  System.out.println("OriginURL set to 1");
  count = 0;
  OriginURL = 1;
  //req.setAttribute("OriginURL", "Register_Call");
 }